# POST Discord Message Embed

Tags: javascript, arrays, post, get, discord

Here is what Im using sending JSON body data.

```
{

"reactions": [

{

"count": 1,

"me": false,

"emoji": {

"id": null,

"name": ""

}

}

],

"attachments": [],

"tts": false,

"embeds": [],

"timestamp": "2017-07-11T17:27:07.299000+00:00",

"mention_everyone": false,

"id": "334385199974967042",

"pinned": false,

"edited_timestamp": null,

"author": {

"username": "Mason",

"discriminator": "9999",

"id": "53908099506183680",

"avatar": "a_bab14f271d565501444b2ca3be944b25"

},

"mention_roles": [],

"content": "Supa Hot",

"channel_id": "290926798999357250",

"mentions": [],

"type": 0

}
```

I only recive the image below. I dont get any embed messages or anything I only get where "Content" is located.

So in theory you need JSON body data to embed messages, I am using a program that sends POST & GET requests. Discord will only take "content" data and post it in my webhook channel. I need to embed a message using JSON data. No language here, just the JSON data, its a program that you enter the varable & data then it will send it. SO I am not using java script or anything.

[What It Sends Via Webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoSK8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of data in your payload that is not recognized by the Discord webhook. Allowed main tags are *username, avatar_url, content, embeds, tts, file*. So plain text can go to *content*, which in your case has worked successfully. Everything more fancy needs to be in the sub-content of *embeds*.

The best reference, I did found so far is [this one](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/).

I also suggest to preview your JSON-code in [this tool](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/).

So reduced to what works from your example, it is only this stuff:

```
{
  "username": "Mason",
  "avatar_url": "http://your.domain.here/a_bab14f271d565501444b2ca3be944b25",
  "content": "Supa Hot",
  "tts": false
}
```